# Can not run without x-server running. No terminals

Tags: command-line, xorg

I'm having problems with my nVidia configuration so I decided to shut down X, re-generate the `xorg.conf` file, and give that a go. I log out and at the login screen I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to the first terminal screen. My monitors indicate there's no signal. Other terminals are the same. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> brings them back to life with the login screen again.

What happened to my terminals?

I've tried this with GDM and LIGHTDM (I don't know if it even makes a difference). Upon switching to anything other than X (e.g. anything other than <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) my monitors go blue (no signal) and go into standby after the standard delay.

Comment: When running X, in a terminal type
ps auxww |fgrep tty  
Are the tty1-7 shown?